# UltraEdit: How to search only in the first line

Tags: ultraedit

I have a DAT file with multiple lines and I want to search only on the first line. 
For example, my DAT file contains this text:

```
Field1þField2þField3þField4þ
JohnþUKþStevenageþ9012þ
MerlitþUSAþBelAirþ56þ
```

I want to search how many fields I have (in this case, there are 4). If I search for þ, the search is executed across all rows and I get 12 for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the first line in the file (SHIFT+END if your cursor is at start of file). You can then go to the Find dialog box and you should see an option to only search "Selected text".

Update: I'm using UltraEdit version 22.10.0.12

[image]

Comment: The "Count All" option from Find is disabled if I have "Selected Text" option. If I switch to "Current File" or "All Open Files", the option is enabled. Do you have the same behavior? I am using UltraEdit version 14.

Comment: I updated my answer to include my UltraEdit version and a screenshot of the line selected and the "Count all" results.